# Spring Data JPA and JDBC template

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I'm working on Spring Boot Application and I use Spring Data, HikariCP and JDBC, but I have a problem.

Inside one method I get a particular `User` from the database using a Spring Data repository. After I get the `User` from the DB I use `JdbcTemplate.query` to get some other information from the DB with `username` of above `User` but the application freezes and after some time it throws

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30006ms.
```

When I debug the code I see that `jdbctemplate` is using hikariCP as `datasource`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 public User getUser() {

     User user = userRepository.findByUsernameAndEnabledTrue("username");

     List<String> roles=  getUserRoles(user.getUsername())

     return user;

 }

 private List<String> getUserRoles(String username) {

     List<String> roles = this.jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT ga.authority FROM group_authorities ga INNER JOIN group_members gm ON gm.group_id = ga.group_id INNER JOIN users u ON gm.username=u.username WHERE u.username=?;",
         new Object[]{username},new ResultSetExtractor<List<String>>() {
             @Override
             public List<String> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                 List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
                 while (resultSet.next()) {
                     roles.add(resultSet.getString("authority"));
                 }
                 return roles;
             }
         });
     return roles;
 }
```

I made a research how to use those together and share same transaction or something like but unfortunately can't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the `JdbcTemplate` uses a different connection than your repository. And since the connection pool makes only one connection available and that is already used by the repository, you run into the timeout.

Increasing the capacity of the connection pool would fix that immediate problem, but the repository and the `JdbcTemplate` would use different connections and therefore transactions, which you probably don't want.

You don't show where your `JdbcTemplate` gets it's connection from, but that is probably where things go wrong. To fix it get the `EntityManager` injected. Then get the `Connection` from it. How to do that is JPA implementation dependent. Here are the versions [for Eclipse Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6707510/66686) and [for Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6707318/66686). Then use that `Connection` to create your `JdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible just inject `DataSource` or `JdbcTemplate` in a custom repository, for example. And if JPA and JDBC calls are inside one transaction (generated by `@Transactional`, for example), Spring is smart enough to use `JPATransactionManager` for both cases with the same transaction and connection.

https://billykorando.com/2019/05/06/jpa-or-sql-in-a-spring-boot-application-why-not-both/